# Possible to launch JWS applet within browser instead of standalone?

Tags: java, applet, embedding, jnlp, java-web-start

Is it possible to embed an applet in HTML so that it will be displayed within the browser window yet launched through Java Web Start via a JNLP file instead of using the browser's Java plugin?  If so, how is this done?

I've only been able to launch my applet in a standalone window, but disliking the user experience pop-ups create, I'd prefer that it be embedded in the browser window.

I'd like to use JWS instead of the plugin because I need to control my applet's maximum heap size, which I don't believe is possible with the browser plugin, at least not on Mac OS 10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-browser applets support JNLP deployment since 1.5 (or so). There's an example on how to do it here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

You're still using the Java plugin then, of course. It may or may not work to set the heap size.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that example is useful. 

You're right, that does allow for launching via a JNLP.  It doesn't appear heap size adjustments are obeyed though when I use that method, unfortunately.

I suppose it just isn't possible to have my cake and eat it too.